# Installer not booting on my Ryzen (3 3200G) system

Tags: system-installation, amd

I was hoping the updated hardware stack was going to increase my odds of success.

Aside from some network issues (detects speed and duplex wrong)and some sleep issues, the same thumb drive installed and runs pretty much fine on my Intel box.  Assuming I may need a newer kernel on the install thumb drive? I've seen methods of updating it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with Pop! or other distros?

Comment: I do not. I've run Arch, Fedora, Pop!, Solus, and most flavors of Ubuntu on that box successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the newest released ISO with the 5.1.1 update? It includes a very recent kernel.

I'm running eOS (and Manjaro) on my main PC (gaming) with a Ryzen 3600, and being doing that for a few months now, so I know it's not a CPU thing. Also, the 3200G includes Ryzen+ arch (not Ryzen2) which makes it even more compatible.

Make sure you re-download the ISO and try again with the latest and greatest.

Comment: Worth a shot, I guess. It is indeed the latest ISO from this week.  I'll try downloading fresh and writing to a different USB drive as well.